# pmwiki+ iis+ fastcgi Permissions partially dened

Tags: iis, fastcgi, pmwiki

Recently ,I meet a problem ,that deploy pmwiki on our iis server,all things goes well.However,the problem occured,that ,our pmwiki has six group ,as we all know that,wiki must allow people to edit it content,the directory is like this:

![enter image description here][1]

the problem is that,I can change the defualt page ,howerver,can not edit the Group1~Group6 folder.
the iis setting is like this:
IE browser :http://your.domain/Group2/?n=Main.HomePage?action=edit
then the browse occured error:HTTP ERROR 405 POST DID NOT ALLOWED
how can I solve this problem ?

![enter image description here][2]

when i want to change the content of everygroup ,for example:

Answer (score 0):

After F12 chrome debug, I found that it did not support HTTP  POST method!